# Is there any way to Edit row of bound fields in gridview with custom edit button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have made an application in asp.net vs 2010

In which I created a `GridView`

Like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" 
    Height="211px" Width="344px">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText ="MessageNumber" DataField = "MessageNumber" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText = "From" DataField = "From" />
      <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText = "Subject" 
           DataNavigateUrlFields = "MessageNumber" 
           DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "~/InboxDetails.aspx?MessageNumber={0}" 
           DataTextField = "Subject" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText = "Date" DataField = "DateSent" />
   </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

You can see here I have only bound fields and there is not any text box or template fields.

Now I want to edit these bound fields with my custom edit button is there any way to edit these fields with out using textboxes and other controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is possible ;-)

But you have to decide how you want the edit to be done. If you're not using the built in functionality to enable editing of the field contents, you need some other kind of editing. One option would be to use a separate details view beneath/besides the table that can be edited. Place the detail view in an update panel to avoid reloading the entire page.

You would also need to place the grid view in an update panel to be able to reload it's content smoothly once the edited changes are saved.